# Filter by location and attribute in field calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-expression

I need to filter values in an array with a certain field value

Below works quite well

```
array_length(
    overlay_contains(
        'UPRNs_Fibre_Status_5f6488b0_aa3b_4f7d_ae6b_025ff9024f2e',
        $id
    )
)
```

However, I need to filter values with the following expression

`to_date("Delivery_Actual_End__c") < make_date(2022,08,22) AND "CDS Milestone View v2_In Contract"`

Comment: Why don't you use: `array_length(overlay_contains('UPRNs_Fibre_Status_5f6488b0_aa3b_4f7d_ae6b_025ff9024f2e', $id, filter:=to_date("Delivery_Actual_End__c" ) < make_date(2022,08,22) AND "CDS Milestone View v2_In Contract"  =  'Yes'))`

Comment: Worked well, thanks. It's really slow to calculate for over 1k polygons but I reckon that's only way to do without using processing tools.

Comment: Yes, this is because this expression is a kind of aggregate funtion so it evaluates each feature 1k times in total it's 1m times the function evaluate features.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could be faster if you first filter features with the simpler filter, and then you filter by location. Try this:

```
array_length(
    array_filter(
        aggregate(
            layer:='UPRNs_Fibre_Status_5f6488b0_aa3b_4f7d_ae6b_025ff9024f2e',
            aggregate:='array_agg',
            expression:=$geometry,
            filter:=
                to_date("Delivery_Actual_End__c") < make_date(2022, 08, 22)
                AND
                "CDS Milestone View v2_In Contract" = 'Yes'
        ),
        contains(
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    )
)
```