# QGIS count points in polygon by category

Tags: layers, point-in-polygon, count, big-data

This question is following to this answer [point count in polygon by category](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438951/175499)

```
array_length(overlay_intersects('pointlayername',$id,filter:="fieldcontainingcategory"='nameofcategory'))
```

This answer worked form me if there is small polygon dataset, but if there is very big dataset then counting freezes.

But my polygon dataset consist of 500 000 (half million) polygon features.
Can you offer an alternative solution for processing large volumes of data, the result of which would be analogous to the image.

[image: Big data point count in polygon flow]

Comment: There are two other answers in the post you linked, Virtual layer and PyQGIS. Did you try these?

Comment: Try to apply first the filter that's easier to compute and then the location filter. Similar to this expression: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439501/202120, or for your case use this [Google Drive File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1reg_OAUzxA2EMNB5d6e34SJHIb1CYvPh/view?usp=sharing)